# How do I use the "custom" PowerPlay power profile in amdgpu?

Tags: linux, amd-graphics

I have a AMD RX 580 on my laptop running Manjaro, using amdgpu and mesa 20.3.1. If I run `cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_power_profile_mode` in a terminal, I get the following output:

```
NUM        MODE_NAME     SCLK_UP_HYST   SCLK_DOWN_HYST SCLK_ACTIVE_LEVEL     MCLK_UP_HYST   MCLK_DOWN_HYST MCLK_ACTIVE_LEVEL
  0   BOOTUP_DEFAULT:        -                -                -                -                -                -
  1   3D_FULL_SCREEN:        0              100               30                0              100               10
  2   POWER_SAVING *:       10                0               30                0              100               10
  3            VIDEO:        -                -                -               10               16               31
  4               VR:        0               11               50                0              100               10
  5          COMPUTE:        0                5               30                -                -                -
  6           CUSTOM:        -                -                -                -                -                -
```

There's various predefined modes that are displayed, but there is a "CUSTOM" mode as well with no values set.

I found https://dri.freedesktop.org/docs/drm/gpu/amdgpu.html#pp-power-profile-mode which says the following about this:

> To select a profile or create a custom profile, first select manual using power_dpm_force_performance_level. Writing the number of a predefined profile to pp_power_profile_mode will enable those heuristics. To create a custom set of heuristics, write a string of numbers to the file starting with the number of the custom profile along with a setting for each heuristic parameter. Due to differences across asic families the heuristic parameters vary from family to family.

I can run `echo "2" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_power_profile_mode` to change the current mode to "POWER_SAVING", but from reading that documentation I believe I should be able to run `echo "6 10 0 30 0 100 10" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_power_profile_mode` to set up the "CUSTOM" mode? However I just get `bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument` in return.

Is it possible to redefine the "CUSTOM" mode here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pp_power_profile_mode` for my RX 470 seems to be the same as your RX 580 (both Polaris cards), and I can change and enable the `CUSTOM` profile by doing something like:

`echo "6 1 50 250 20 1 250 250 20" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_power_profile_mode`

I think the parameters are (in order):

1. `NUM` The mode selection, which is `6` for custom.
2. `ENABLE_SCLK` Whether the core clock parameters set here should be applied or not.
3. `SCLK_UP_HYST` Delay in ms before the core clock goes up.
4. `SCLK_DOWN_HYST` Delay in ms before the core clock goes down.
5. `SCLK_ACTIVE_LEVEL` Core load required to increase the core clock.
6. `ENABLE_MCLK` Whether the memory clock parameters set here should be applied or not.
7. `MCLK_UP_HYST` Delay in ms before the memory clock goes up.
8. `MCLK_DOWN_HYST` Delay in ms before the memory clock goes down.
9. `MCLK_ACTIVE_LEVEL` Memory load required to increase the memory clock.

The `ENABLE` parameters 2 and 6 can be `1` (enabled) or `0` (disabled). The `HYST` parameters 3, 4, 7, and 8 can be `0` to `254` ms or `255` (infinite). The `ACTIVE_LEVEL` parameters can be `0` to `100` percent active level (load).

The default `3D_FULL_SCREEN` profile has core settings `0 100 30` and memory settings `0 100 10`. My goal was to get high performance while playing games, but low power consumption while not. So I set a core clock that goes up a bit slower and goes down a lot slower, but is more sensitive to core load (`0 100 30` → `50 250 20`). And I set a memory clock that goes up and down slowly and is less sensitive to memory load (`0 100 10` → `250 250 20`), so the voltage doesn't jump from 800 mV to 1000+ mV all the time (which happens when memory clocks are increased, even if the core clock is only 300 MHz).

Answer (score 0):

For my 5700XT my `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_power_profile_mode` looks like this:

```
PROFILE_INDEX(NAME) CLOCK_TYPE(NAME) FPS MinFreqType MinActiveFreqType MinActiveFreq BoosterFreqType BoosterFreq PD_Data_limit_c PD_Data_error_coeff PD_Data_error_rate_coeff
 0 BOOTUP_DEFAULT :
                    0(       GFXCLK)       0       5       1       0       4     800 4587520  -65536       0
                    1(       SOCCLK)       0       5       1       0       3     800 1310720   -6553       0
                    2(        MEMLK)       0       5       1       0       4     800  327680  -65536       0
 1 3D_FULL_SCREEN :
                    0(       GFXCLK)       0       5       1       0       4     650 3932160   -6553  -65536
                    1(       SOCCLK)       0       5       1     850       4     800 1310720   -6553       0
                    2(        MEMLK)       0       5       4     850       4     800  327680  -65536       0
 2   POWER_SAVING*:
                    0(       GFXCLK)       0       5       1       0       3       0 5898240  -65536       0
                    1(       SOCCLK)       0       5       1       0       3       0 1310720   -6553       0
                    2(        MEMLK)       0       5       1       0       3       0 1966080  -65536       0
 3          VIDEO :
                    0(       GFXCLK)       0       5       1       0       4     500 4587520  -65536       0
                    1(       SOCCLK)       0       5       1       0       4     500 1310720   -6553       0
                    2(        MEMLK)       0       5       1       0       4     500 1966080  -65536       0
 4             VR :
                    0(       GFXCLK)       0       5       4    1000       4     800 4587520  -65536       0
                    1(       SOCCLK)       0       5       1       0       4     800  327680  -65536       0
                    2(        MEMLK)       0       5       1       0       4     800  327680  -65536       0
 5        COMPUTE :
                    0(       GFXCLK)       0       5       4    1000       3       0 3932160  -65536  -65536
                    1(       SOCCLK)       0       5       4     850       3       0  327680  -65536  -32768
                    2(        MEMLK)       0       5       4     850       3       0  327680  -65536  -32768
 6         CUSTOM :
                    0(       GFXCLK)       0       5       1       0       4     800 4587520  -65536       0
                    1(       SOCCLK)       0       5       1       0       3     800 1310720   -6553       0
                    2(        MEMLK)       0       5       1       0       4     800  327680  -65536       0
```

It contains heuristics for changing power levels (which can be set in `pp_od_clk_voltage`) only if the **`manual`** mode has been selected in `power_dpm_force_performance_level` [according to the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/gpu/amdgpu.html#power-dpm-force-performance-level).

I can set custom values for the `CUSTOM` profile (with idx 6) and component (`GFXCLK` = 0, `SOCCLK` = 1, `MEMLK` = 2) like this:

```
echo '6 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9' | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_power_profile_mode
```

The file then contains:

```
 6         CUSTOM*:
                    0(       GFXCLK)       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
                    1(       SOCCLK)       0       5       1       0       3     800 1310720   -6553       0
                    2(        MEMLK)       0       5       1       0       4     800  327680  -65536       0
```

However it's still a mystery to me what these values *mean*...